# r.to.vect is not responding in QGIS GRASS

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, performance, nlcd

NLCD data entered for half of Illinois, all of Michigan and Wisconsin, plus additional along borders.

Used `r.neighbors` to simplify, then `r.to.vect` with *"smooth corners"* feature selected.

Got one warning

> Concurrent mapset locking is not supported on Windows.

Got to *"Registering primitives..."* and has been there nearly three days.

Task Manager indicates 25% to 30% CPU utilization, approximately 500 MB or more Memory use with Power usage High to Very High. Running on i3-2379M CPU @2.4 GHz with 6.00 GB Memory, 64-bit Windows 10.

Should I let it run or *"End Task"*?

Comment: 6GB RAM at 2.4Ghz is on the moped side of the vehicular comparison scale for GIS.

Comment: Furthermore, the area you describe must be about 700-1000 km wide and high. The NLCD data are at 30 meter resolution, so you must have a region of some 30,000 x 30,000 pixels. Assuming that most land cover clusters are small, you'll be trying to create a vector with probably hundreds of millions of little polygons.

Comment: We're into the 4th day of processing but it's still chugging along. Sometimes memory use is as much as 900 MB. I know it's a slow machine but that's all I have right now. Would it be better to try half the data at a time? I've been thinking I could "split" the data generation north to south, about in the middle of Lake Michigan for most of the "seam". Might the seam cause problems later?

Comment: (Note: the message "Concurrent mapset locking is not supported on Windows." is harmless and unrelated to the problem).

Comment: Day 5: Memory use is 1800 MB to as high as 2800 MB today. Disk speed was close to 0 MB/s (.1 to .3 MB/s) but is now from 2.7 MB/s to 5.7MB/s. Maybe it's in a different stage of processing?

Comment: So, on Day 5 r.to.vect complete!! However, following is message: Warning 1: 2GB file size limit reached for (NCLD filename.shp). Going on, but might cause campatibility issues with third party software     ERROR 1:Failed to write shape object. File size cannot reach 4294962072 + 5724.
Exporting 5519942 areas (may take some time)...
5..11..17..23..29..35..41..47..53..59..65..71..77..83..89..ERROR: Failed to create OGR feature ERROR: Unable to open database <$GISDBASE/$LOCATION_NAME/$MAPSET/sqlite/sqlite.db>  Execution completed in (large number) seconds.  Thanks to all above for your insight!

Comment: You are apparently trying to export more than 2 GB into a SHAPE file. See here how to deal with it in GDAL/OGR: https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/shapefile.html#size-issues

Comment: Thank you, markusN!